# Context not available?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

Im playing around trying to create a custom activity in wf4.  I found a tutorial / example and have been using this to get started, however i seem to have a problem.

```
public sealed class SaveRequest : NativeActivity {
    // Define an activity input argument of type string
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<Request> Request { get; set; }

    // If your activity returns a value, derive from CodeActivity<TResult>
    // and return the value from the Execute method.
    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context) {
        Request Request = this.Request.Get(context);
        Request.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Request.Title = "New Test";
        RequestMonkeyRepository Rep = new RequestMonkeyRepository();
        Rep.save(Request);
    }
}
```

The code above always errors out with an null object instance when assigning the guid.  Im presuming its because i havent passed the request object to the workflow, but i cant see how they did this in the example.

Im running a console app and my execution code is below

```
WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(new RequestMonkeyTest1.TestWorkflow());
```

Comment: `Request` isn't set by magic.  You must bind it to *something*.  That *something* has to be passed into the workflow *somehow*.

Comment: @Will thanks for that.  I cant see how they've done that in the example but think ive figured it out.  Im passing a idictionary object to the workflow.  not there yet but getting close

Comment: Notice you gave a string value as the index of your Request object passed to the workflow?  SaveRequest.Request must be bound to that value.  The string index must be the name of an argument defined on the root of the workflow, and Request must be bound to this argument.  So, by name, the instance is passed to the workflow, the workflow populates the argument, and then as SaveRequest executes the binding is evaluated and the Request instance is retrieved from the workflow context.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the Request InArgument in your workflow to some expression that returns an instance of a Request object? If not try adding "new Request()" in the expression and run your workflow again.

Comment: psst, [I just submitted a bug report involving wf4](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/715057/wf-activity-validation-does-not-respect-object-oriented-principals-in-certain-situations).  If you happen to have a moment to view and comment I'd appreciate it.  Might be a while before the attached solution is available to download, tho.

Comment: psst psst I just figured out what *"Assembly references and imported namespaces for internal implementation"* means!  It means **hocus pocus!  validation will now work correctly!**